# Undefined control sequence due to \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, biber, apa-style

I am currently writing my master's thesis using TeX Live and Texmaker and have suddenly run into an "undefined control sequence" that points to the line

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

in my preamble. However, this error only surfaces on the second run of pdflatex when all .aux-files etc. are deleted in the respective folder. With pre-existing files, this happens already on the first run.

My current preamble (shortened):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{JabRefDB.bib}
\begin{document}
\include{TitlePage} %removed several chapters of text
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\include{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

The errors I am receiving are several lines long, thus I have added only the first two:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@theformat #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8->\nameparts
{#1}\ifthenelse {\value {listcou...
l.48 ...raphy[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...artprefix \namepartfamily }\ifempty
{\namepartprefix }{}{\mkbi...
l.48 ...raphy[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
The control sequence ...
```

I have been looking for an answer for several hours, but cannot seem to find the root cause of this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try writing it without the curly brackets, as in `title=References`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the errors are the same after removing the curly brackets.

Comment: That's odd. Try adding `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}` to your preamble.

Comment: In version 3.3 of `biblatex` the name handling was substantially revised. `biblatex-apa` v 6.8 already uses the new name handling and has been available on CTAN (and MikTeX) for a few days now. `biblatex` 3.3, however, has only just arrived at CTAN, so it might take another day or so to propagate to all mirrors and TeX Live and MikTeX.

Comment: So the solution is to wait until `biblatex` 3.3 and Biber 2.4 become available and then make an update. If you absolutely cannot wait you can manually install `biblatex` 3.3 and Biber 2.4 from sourceforge ([`biblatex` link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-3.3/), [biber link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/2.4/)). Since the changes are quite substantial I can't offer an easy work-around.

Comment: @Alenanno Note that the curly braces in `title={References}` are perfectly fine here; granted, it would also work without the braces in this case. But there are situations where they are required, `title={Foo, Bar}` for example. While `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}` would probably work here, with `biblatex` I would prefer a solution that redefines the bibliography strings `bibliography` and `references` if I were to change the bibliography title.

Comment: I find constructions such as `style=apa,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=apa` a bit meh. If you want a properly APA compliant document, use `style=apa` only; if you want to mix `authoryear` and `apa` in the way you currently do, go with `citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=apa` (but I don't think that is a good idea).

Comment: Yes, this is because APA 6.8 requires biblatex 3.3 and biber 2.4 and things are not quite in sync in CTAN yet. You can get biblatex/biber from sourceforge if you need to.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I had thought about this possibility, but was unsure. I am going to wait and hope both updates will be available soon. Also, I have noted your suggestion, moewe and will use `style=apa` only. How should I go about marking this question as solved?

Comment: If there is a canonical question about the importance of ensuring `biblatex`, `biber`(and `biblatex`-dependent packages) are all in sync version-wise, then this question should be closed with a link to that question. If there is no 'version' question on this site, perhaps one could be made so questions like this could all point to it.

Comment: @jon I don't think there is a canonical question, but the issue is probably touched on in quite some answers. This is because normally version questions are resolved by an update and those questions are often closed as off-topic. Do you think this site would benefit from a go-to `biblatex` version question?

Comment: @moewe -- I wonder. I have certainly seen it come up in several questions. I don't think it is an urgent need, to be sure, and I suppose people suffering from a version mismatch would be unlikely to search for that problem. But closing these sorts of questions with a link to a version mismatch Q&A probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @jon So how would you go about doing this? Do you have a good question in mind that we could use? Or do you think it would be better to start an "artificial" new one?

Comment: @moewe -- I think an artificial question is likely the easiest route. I know I've seen the issue come up before, but I am not eager to track down the question(s). If you want to draft (and answer) an artificial question, I'd defer to your expertise. Or it could be asked on meta first. I think people would be in favour, but I'm not an expert on the de facto (or de iure) policy for this site.

Comment: @jon I'm a bit snowed under at the moment, but I think it is a good idea to find out what other people think on meta, so if you want to do that please go ahead. (I think we had a meta question for the Biber editor thing as well.)

Comment: @moewe -- Sure; see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6572/852

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that it is indeed working again with the latest updated packages. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a temporary version mismatch on CTAN that has since been resolved, the issue is solved by an update (see comment above).